# Jquery.load() not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, load, cross-browser

I am having a very odd problem with jQuery .load(). The code below is woking fine in Safari but is delivering **null value** data in FireFox. However, when I check the response it is saying **success**.

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false}) ;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27 && $("#MasterEditHelper").val() == 1)   {
        var No = $("#MasterEdit").attr("value");
        var Id = "#Box-"+No;
        var viewType = $('#ViewType').val();
        $(Id).html('<p class="updating">UPDATING</p>');

        $(Id).load("/Styles/Zoom/Update", {id : No, view : viewType});


        $("#MasterEdit").css('display' , 'none');       
        $("#MasterEditHelper").val(0);
        $("#sub-duvet").fadeIn();
        } 
});
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: r u using an mvc framework? if so, then the request would probably be successful but no data would be returned, also make sure that you are using correct url, try to keep all them lowercase, as it is possible that some browser would not work correctly that way

Comment: also please supply more code, i dont think one can help you with this.

Comment: The url is correct as it is working in other browsers. I have tried different pages, including a test ajax page that just gives a `<p>Success</p>`result and I still got Null. The remainder of the code is not essential as all is - showing a div, setting the value of the div to 1. Upon escape the above is called.

Comment: UPDATE - I managed to fix the problem. It seems that the load does not fire if it is under the keydown() function. Changed the action to a button and it now works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Could you check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/kVdXZ/3/

Tried recreating your script, and it seems to be working fine in firefox and others.

So it seems it's your URL that might be causing the problems?